# Formatting dates and times with as.POSIXct in R

Tags: r, posixct

I am attempting to format a column of dates and time (datetime) from my file "f845" using as.POSIXct in R. The file 845 has 21 lines to skip before formatting as seen in the first line of code below, it also has two columns and 100000 rows.

When I attempt to format the datetime column with the second line of code below I end up with the output as seen in the data below the 3rd line.

How come my code is not formatting the date and time properly?

```
> dat=read.table(f845,sep="\t",skip=21,col.names=c("datetime","light"))
> dat$datetime=as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$datetime,format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"))
> dat[1:10,]
   datetime  time
1      <NA> 4.542
2      <NA> 7.949
3      <NA> 5.678
4      <NA> 7.949
5      <NA> 7.949
6      <NA> 6.813
7      <NA> 2.271
8      <NA> 2.271
9      <NA> 2.271
10     <NA> 2.271
```

Here is what the data looks like before the formatting:

```
> dat=read.table(f845,sep="\t",skip=21,col.names=c("datetime","light"))
> dat[1:10,]
              datetime light
1  21/05/2013 22:56:07 4.542
2  21/05/2013 23:01:07 7.949
3  21/05/2013 23:06:07 5.678
4  21/05/2013 23:11:07 7.949
5  21/05/2013 23:16:07 7.949
6  21/05/2013 23:21:07 6.813
7  21/05/2013 23:26:07 2.271
8  21/05/2013 23:31:07 2.271
9  21/05/2013 23:36:07 2.271
10 21/05/2013 23:41:07 2.271
```

Edit: the output of `dput(droplevels (dput(dat[1:10,]))` is shown below, there is still a large number of dates so I only show the last few lines:

```
> dput(droplevels(dat[1:10,]))
structure(list(datetime = structure(1:10, .Label = c("21/05/2013 22:56:07", 
"21/05/2013 23:01:07", "21/05/2013 23:06:07", "21/05/2013 23:11:07", 
"21/05/2013 23:16:07", "21/05/2013 23:21:07", "21/05/2013 23:26:07", 
"21/05/2013 23:31:07", "21/05/2013 23:36:07", "21/05/2013 23:41:07"
), class = "factor"), light = c(4.542, 7.949, 5.678, 7.949, 7.949, 
6.813, 2.271, 2.271, 2.271, 2.271)), .Names = c("datetime", "light"
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(dat$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`  You used `-` instead of `/`

Comment: I am still receiving "NA" in all the rows.

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(dat[1:10,])`

Comment: It does work on the first 10 lines, I neglected to mention that the file has 100000 rows. I have added that info to the question.

Comment: It may be better to check whether you have multiple formats in the file. ie. some rows with `21/05/2013...` some with `21-05-2013..`.  Check if `sum(!grepl("[/]", dat$datetime))` >0

Comment: I think you pasted only a part of `dput(dat[1:10,])` output (which is not useful)

Comment: I receive a "FALSE" with `sum(!grepl("[/]", dat$datetime)) >0`

Comment: Not posting the full results of `dput()` completely defeats the purpose. It seems you are reading your date time values in as factors which is probably not what you want. But try `droplevels(dput(dat[1:10,])` to get rid of extra levels.

Comment: In this simple test, everything seems to work: `ok<-read.table(text=c("21/05/2013 22:56:07\t4.542","21/05/2013 23:01:07\t7.949
"), sep="\t", col.names=c("datetime","light")); as.POSIXct(ok$datetime,  format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`. How is your data different?

Comment: I entered in `ok<-read.table(f845, sep="\t", skip=21,col.names=c("datetime","light")); as.POSIXct(ok$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` and it is formatting fine now. I will add drop levels to the question.

Comment: @JC11 I can have a look at the file if you can share it in dropbox.

Comment: And sorry, i meant `dput(droplevels(dat[1:10,]))`. That should make the output much shorter so you can post the whole thing. Posting a partial `dput` is never helpful. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @akrun https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uoi9hxkykhn3zct/AAB1QYnYNjXgj_vp3ICm7BLya?dl=0

Comment: Thank you akrun and Mr Flick, it is working fine. Although I suspected this would solve another issue I was having, but it is not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370985/error-reading-dataset-regarding-differing-number-of-rows-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error might be due to using `-` instead of `/` in the `format`.

```
 dat <- read.table("D845.lux",sep="\t",skip=21,
        col.names=c("datetime","light"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  dim(dat)
 #[1] 100247      2

  Datetime <- as.POSIXct(dat$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  head(Datetime)
  #[1] "2013-05-21 22:56:07 EDT" "2013-05-21 23:01:07 EDT"
  #[3] "2013-05-21 23:06:07 EDT" "2013-05-21 23:11:07 EDT"
  #[5] "2013-05-21 23:16:07 EDT" "2013-05-21 23:21:07 EDT"

  any(is.na(Datetime))
 #[1] FALSE
```